# How to move contour of selection instead of content of selection (GIMP)?

Tags: gimp, selections, shortcuts

I was able to do so, but those buttons gone (probably compatability with new hardware issue) , but anyway I need some workaround - shortcut or using a menu bar.
How I was doing it in the past:
I selected some area, then Move Tool and then there buttons appeared (under all tools icons): button for moving selected pixels, button for moving shape of selection itself (contour)...

Comment: I don't understand your question. The Selection toggle is located inside the tool options for the Move tool. It's not "gone". [You can see it here](https://imgur.com/xChatBw). Have you lost the Tool options dialog?  Have you tried enabling it using Windows > Dockable dialogs > Tool options?

Comment: @Billy Kerr that's it, thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, you use the Move tool, in "Move selection" mode (red square icon in the "Move" line in the Tool options), to move the selection mask.

The Rectangle and Ellipse selection can be moved directly while in the selection tool by clicking inside and dragging.

See [here](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-selections.html#gimp-using-selections-moving) for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

If your move tool happens to be in "move layer" mode or "move path" mode, hold Alt as you drag. Then the active selection moves.